# Верно ли окончание глагола после аббревиатуры "ООО"?

Tags: окончания, сокращения

«...ООО "..." начало разбирать здание». Верно ли окончание глагола от среднего рода?

Comment: А какие слова стоят на месте первого многоточия?

Comment: просто кусок текста...

Comment: А зачем тогда первые кавычки у Вас стоят? И ещё: а "просто кусок текста" не содержит ли, к примеру, слово "компания"?

Comment: ну ладно, придираетесь....чтобы выглядело эффектно)

Comment: нет «компании» итд...

Answer (score 2):

Верно: видовое наименование "общество" из общеизвестной аббревиатуры "ООО" управляет глаголом-сказуемым «сильнее» любого приводимого после него названия.